# Windows 8 Update Locked

Tags: windows-8, login, updates

I just turned on my laptop today it loaded up and then immediately turned off.  On the 2nd boot, it says

```
Windows Update
Your PC will restart in 2 days to finish installing important updates.
```

I cannot do anything, no login or shutdown.  Anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Random thing I'd try to do: reboot, set your laptop's date to next Wednesday in BIOS, then check what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a Microsoft issue they will fix soon to a more pleasant and "loggin-able" solution. That is caused because you updated your system and did not choose to restart manually.

AAMOF there is nothing you can do right now.

source:

http://windows8forums.com/windows-8-updates/16949-2-days-windows-update.html

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/message-stating-your-pc-will-restart-in-2-days-to/4c358e47-2e99-4287-b0c8-f6981bd8018d

Comment: Is it really going to take 2 days before I can use my computer, is it?  I hope I'm just misreading it.

Comment: for what i have read so far... i am afraid so.

Comment: . . . i hope not

Answer (score 3):

- Login to your locked computer via Remote Desktop from another computer on your network (here's hoping you've got one).
- Remote desktop gets you in just fine (no nasty "your computer will restart" hang-up).  From here
- OPTION 1 (my recommendation): Save all your unsaved files and close all your open apps from the Remote Desktop session.  Then restart from there.
- OPTION 2 (worked for me but can't guarantee it for others): DISCONNECT (don't logoff) your remote desktop session (this is where you click in the "X" on the RD Windows bar that appears when you hover the mouse near the top of a full-screen RD session).  Go back to your locked computer and click the screen and you'll be prompted that you're already logged in from the other computer.  Click through that and you'll magically get the password control to unlock your computer.  From there, better save/close everything and reboot while you've still got access.